# Implementing disqus within a mobile app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch, disqus

I have a problem implementing Disqus in an app created with sencha touch and phonegap. The web app developed by Sencha Touch Disqus is working fine, however when I make a build through phonegap to Android or iOS, the disqus comment doesn't show.

I implement the script in a Sencha x-Panel with HTML properties.

Comment: Are you loading Disqus on a page hosted internal to the phone, or is it an externally-accessible page?

Comment: It's a view hosted in the device.

Comment: Got it, will write the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for the Disqus embed to load, it must come from a valid referrer - typically this referrer when on the phone is something like the file system path.

The ideal way to handle this is to host the Disqus embed on an external page and load that into your view. You can even load this on a static cdn using this example: https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/tree/master/mobile/js

Comment: Many thanks Ryan. In fact, I hosted the code in a dynamic page and it's working perfect. Except I have problem of scrolling in the sencha code.

Comment: I think this has to do something with Sencha's custom scroll container not responding to changes in the Disqus iframe height. You might want to post about that issue on Sencha's forums, but if you can't find a solution, you might need to put this on a regular page.

Comment: @RyanV - can you please borate more, how can I do that? means hosted outside apk? if yes, how it will be embedded in my ionic view?