# How to add Disqus comments in mobile app?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework, disqus

I have made a small app, using Ionic framework and now I'm trying to add Disqus comments into it. But Disqus needs a "trusted domains". 
I haven't any domain, because it's a mobile app, not a website. How can I skirt the ban?

Comment: this question has perfect answer over here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190584/issue-on-implementing-disqus-with-phonegap-and-sencha-touch

Comment: It's because the question that @NehilMistry pointed to is not descriptive enough and too specific in its concern so it might not get caught by someone doing a search for something like ionic-framework. I submitted edits to hopefully make it more broadly searchable.

Comment: Have you considered using the Disqus mobile SDK?